# Align N columns of single characters

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I am attempting to have N number of columns of single characters in C# by outputting a string through a label for each row in WFA.  I attempted to use the solution found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978311/format-a-string-into-columns) using String.Format but I can't since I do not know the number of columns, I also don't think it will work because of the characters not being the same width.

I tried generating a string to be passed as the first argument of String.Format and then supply the array of characters for a row as the second argument, but I get the error `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.` which is confusing since I have guaranteed this to be true.

```
//generatedText is built in a loop consisting of  += "{" + i + ", -2} "
row1.Text = String.Format(generatedText, myCharArray); //error!
```

The trivial solution of just separating each column by a space doesn't work at all because the characters aren't the same width so they quickly get offset (I think String.Format fixes this problem, if I could get it to work).

Any advice on fixing my usage of String.Format or a way to make the text fixed width perhaps, or another solution to my problem?

**EDIT:**  I attempted to use String.Format for a determined amount of columns and it doesn't align them properly because of the different character widths.  Other solutions?

Example output would be something like...

```
Row 1:  a  j  e  t  v  q  p  z  c
Row 2:  c  c  b  r  m  a  s  t  m
```

with the columns lining up perfectly.

Comment: Please provide an example input and the desired output.

Comment: @harpo provided an example desired output

Comment: @ScottHunter Perhaps I have thought too far into this problem!  Can you give an example of a mono spaced font?

Comment: @M.Babcock So Microsoft Sans Serif is not fixed width but Sans Serif is?  Lame on MS's part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reliable way to do what you want unless you use a monospaced font as @Scott-Hunter recommended.  You could fudge it by measuring strings, but with a non-monospaced font there are going to be gaps that you just can't fix using spaces.

With a monospaced font, it's trivial.  Just separate with spaces.  Use Consolas, Courier, etc.

Comment: It looks like I was making this problem much, much harder than it really is.  You and Scott were correct, thanks!