# Dropdown list tabulated C# mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I want to present my data in a "dropdown list tabulated", let me explain.

If the data is like this:

```
Potato - 1.00
Egg - 2.50
Avocado - 3.00
```

I want to present it like this:

```
Potato  - 1.00
Egg     - 2.50
Avocado - 3.00
```

How can I format the dropdown like that?

Let me try make my question more understandable:

I just have to organize the data as it was showed in a dropdonw, making the `-` be the separator of two things, the `vegetable` and `value`, but I want to put this char at end of biggest name item and align another `-` at that point, to show to user like a tabulated data.

Comment: Please think carefully about what you are asking. This question as is makes very little sense.

Comment: The `table` element is specifically designed for tabulated data(hence the name table).  If you create a new view using the Add View dialog and choose Index as the scaffold, it will use a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a dropdown, then you will need to format the strings using a technique like this:
[Format a string into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978311/format-a-string-into-columns)

```
string.Format( "{0,-10} - {1,-10}", item.Name, item.Price)
```

You may also need to do a `.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")` because often HTML ignores duplicate spaces, but this may or may not be the case in a dropdown.

Note you could calculate each column width by finding the longest item and adding 1, so if the longest Name.Length is 5, then

```
string.Format( "{0,-" + longestNameLength + "} - {1,-5}"
```

and maybe -5 for the other if you know it is always a two digit price.

Comment: I've tried to put "&nbsp" before, but at my screen i didn't got the white spaces, I got the string "&nbsp" instead of blank spaces :(

Comment: First, don't forget semicolon, `&nbsp;`, Second, you may need to write the HTML yourself instead of using MVC helpers.  Most MVC helpers will escape special characters like the &.  See works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rZFse/

Comment: Also, you will need to use a "fixed width" font since other fonts, letters like "i" are skinnier than "o" and will throw off alignment.