# formatting the string to look like a table

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which i have initialized to empty and building the string as seen below i have also got the preferred output i would like, whats the best mathod of doing this as this would be sent as an email. tak into account company names will be off different length.

string being buit

```
foreach(string s in array)
{
emailBody += s + "          Success" + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Ouput of String

```
CompanyName    Success
CompanyName       Success
CompanyName         Success
CompanyName           Success
CompanyName         Success
CompanyName            Success
CompanyName          Success
```

Would like output like below

---

```
CompanyName   |   Success
CompanyName   |   Success
CompanyName   |   Success
CompanyName   |   Success
CompanyName   |   Success
CompanyName   |   Success
CompanyName   |   Success
```

Output of Solution given

```
qxeawgentina                                           Success
TweseqmeChile                                           Success
Vidqwedal                                           Success
qwebr                                           Success
Doqa_brasil                                           Success
Sedaqqagentina                                           Success
KnaqwertArtina                                           Success
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `StringBuilder` instead of `+=` <= just a tip

Comment: In addition to what has been said in the answers, make sure you use a monospaced font... otherwise there's no way to properly align the columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx.aspx) is a nice function to use for stuff like this.  You could do something like this:

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string s in array)
{
    myString.Append(s + "Success".PadLeft(15 - s.Length) + Environment.NewLine);
}
emailBody = myString.ToString();
```

Change the constant 15 to be the longest CompanyName you have in your collection, otherwise `PadLeft` will throw an exception when it becomes negative.

(Also `StringBuilder` is a good idea here as mentioned in the comments)

Comment: Tip: add `StringBuilder` here :)

Comment: `15 - s`? It shouldn't be `15 - s.Length` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes it should, also added `StringBuilder`

Comment: @SimonPatel Right so the PadLeft will change based on the length of the company name

Comment: see the output above i dont get the sucess in a line down

Comment: @SimonPatel Are you using a monospaced font?  Also I don't understand how you ended up with some many spaces when 15 is the max it could be, can you post a working sample of code that generated what you are seeing?

Comment: I change the number to 50. i dont know.. that data is conming from a sql databse

Comment: i dont know whether or not I'm using a monospaced font, but the data comes form database and stored on a datatable and the split at commas to make the array

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978311/format-a-string-into-columns)

Basically you can use string.Format and specify widths per placeholder, like so:

```
// Prints "--123       --"
string.Format("--{0,-10}--", 123);
// Prints "--       123--"
string.Format("--{0,10}--", 123);
```

Edit:
Applying this to your example:

```
foreach(string s in array)
{
    emailBody += string.Format("{0, 25} | Success", s) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: i cant do that because its not a consol and i need to keep the whole string as its being sent as an email

Comment: Just use string.Format and put the result in a variable or whatever you need to do with it. ;-) 
Console.WriteLine just happens to accept the same parameters as string.Format

Comment: If it's an email, send it as html

Comment: @SimonPatel, you can do the same with a StringWriter

Answer (score 0):

Trim your string and calculate the longest string length:

```
int maxLength = 0;

foreach(string s in array)
{
    l = s.Trim().Length;
    if (l > maxLength)
    {
        maxLength = l;
    }
}

foreach(string s in array)
{
    emailBody += System.Format("{0,-" + maxLength.ToString() + "}    |    Success" + Environment.NewLine, s.Trim());
}
```

Comment: He wants formatting with columns, trimming won't solve his problem here

Comment: @Moeri Yes I didn't consider the variation of size. I made an update.