# How to Align the sentence which consists of 4 words in windows label as per below spec

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Example:

```
1 Abc          5 cm
2 Bcdef      8.5 mm2
3 D1        0.02 cm
4 Ghijkl    1.23 cm
```

Divide a sentence into 4 Columns in single label based on pixel. 1st column is right aligned, 2nd column is left aligned and 3rd column is right aligned and 4th column is right aligned.

Comment: Why dont you use a control which purpose is to show tabular data like `DataGridView`? If the content is static(so never 5 columns or rows) you could also use multiple labels which you put in a `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978311/format-a-string-into-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a string into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978311/format-a-string-into-columns)