# Java String Formatting (Columns)

Tags: java, string-formatting

Is there a native code or library in Java for formatting a String like in the way below made in C#?

Source: [Format a string into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978311/format-a-string-into-columns#_=_)  (C#)

```
public string DropDownDisplay { 
  get { 
    return String.Format("{0,-10} - {1,-10}, {2, 10} - {3,5}"), 
                          Name, City, State, ID);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Use `String.format(...)` method. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java also have a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) formatting option :

```
public String DropDownDisplay(){
    return String.format("%-10s - %-10s, %10s - %5s", "name", "city", "state", "id");
}
```

There many format specifiers as :

- `%s` - String value
- `%d` - Decimal integer

For specifying a width you can use the `%SomeNumber` option,
positive number will **Right-justify** within the specified width, and a negative number will be **Left-Justify**.
Here is [Java format examples](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) that you can use

Comment: But I want two or more columns side by side. And define for each columns the amount of characters.

Comment: I edit my answer, the %SomeNumber does it,  like C#, please read the example i have put in the answer

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I have searched in Java

Comment: But can you also describe the different between %-10s and %10s? Would be great.

Comment: See documentation in the ``Flags`` section. The minus sign is used for left-alignment, the 10 is the padding width.

Answer (score 4):

Java provides [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) with various options to format both text and numbers.

There is no need for additional libraries, it is a built-in feature.

The syntax is very similar to your example. Basically, to print a String, you can use the `%s` placeholder. For decimal numbers, use `%d`. See my link above to get a full list of all possible types.

```
String name = "Saskia";
int age = 23;
String formattedText = String.format("%s is %d years old.", name, age);
```

You can add flags for additional padding and alignment, if you want a column-like output.

```
String formattedText = String.format("%-10s is %-5d years old.", name, age);
```

In `%-10s` the `%s` defines the type String, the `-` is used for left-alignment and the `10` defines the width of the padding.

Comment: That's not why im searching. I want columns with a specific amount of characters. I know this simple formatting.

Comment: I have updated my anser and included information about formatting flags. See my link, there is a whole section on those flags in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The simple String method `format` provides the same as C's printf.

But the JDK class java.text.MessageFormat provides a very rich set of ways for formatting.